# The record is added without data, but it is null - Angular

Tags: mongodb, angular

The record is added without data, but it is null - Angular 5 and Mongodb ^3.0.1

```
http://localhost:3000/api/users

{
"status":200,
"data":[
  {
     "_id":"5a63f4da17fc7e9e5548da70",
     "name":"Jonson Doeal",
     "password":"password"
  },
  {
     "_id":"5a63faf417fc7e9e5548da71",
     "name":"Jonson Bol",
     "password":"password"
  },
  {
     "_id":"5a64f44de87b3e2f80437c6b",
     "name":"aaaa",
     "password":"aaaa"
  },
  {
     "_id":"5a67e03bb1d1941d7451c0fa",
     "name":null,
     "password":"Highway 37"
  }
],
"message":null
}
```

server/routes/api.js:

```
const express = require('express');
const router = express.Router();
const MongoClient = require('mongodb').MongoClient;
const ObjectID = require('mongodb').ObjectID;


// Connect 27017
const connection = (closure) => {
    return MongoClient.connect('mongodb://localhost:27017/mean', (err, client) => {
        if (err) return console.log(err);
        let db = client.db('mean');
        closure(db);
    });
};

// Error handling
const sendError = (err, res) => {
    response.status = 501;
    response.message = typeof err == 'object' ? err.message : err;
    res.status(501).json(response);
};

// Response handling
let response = {
    status: 200,
    data: [],
    message: null
};



// Get users
router.get('/users', (req, res) => {
    connection((db) => {
        db.collection('users')
            .find()
            .toArray()
            .then((users) => {
                response.data = users;
                res.json(response);
            })
            .catch((err) => {
                sendError(err, res);
            });
    });
});

router.post("/users", (req, client) =>{

    const  myobj = { name: req.body.userName, password: "Highway 37" };

        connection((db) => {
        db.collection('users').insertOne(myobj, (err, doc) =>{           

         });
       });
     });

  module.exports = router;
```

`req.body.userName` ----> is null :

```
{"_id":"5a67e03bb1d1941d7451c0fa","name":null,"password":"Highway 
37"}],"message":null}
```

`db.collection('users').insertOne( req.body, (err, doc) =>{ }` ---> it does not add any values :

```
{"_id":"5a689b767803052e00e76ded"}],"message":null}
```

auth/auth.service.ts:

```
import {Injectable} from '@angular/core';
import {Router} from '@angular/router';
import {BehaviorSubject} from 'rxjs/BehaviorSubject';
import {User} from './user';
import {Http, Headers, RequestOptions, Response} from '@angular/http';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/map';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/toPromise';

@Injectable()

export class AuthService {

  private loggedIn = new BehaviorSubject<boolean>(false);
  result: any;

  get isLoggedIn() {
    return this.loggedIn.asObservable();
  }

  constructor(private router: Router, private _http: Http) {}

  registration(newUser: User): Promise<void | User> {
    return this._http.post('/api/users', newUser)
      .toPromise()
      .then(response => response.json().data as User);
  }

  getUsers() {
    return this._http.get('/api/users').map(result => this.result = result.json().data);
  }


}
```

auth/user.ts:

```
export interface User {
  userName: string;
  password: string;
}
```

registration/registration.ts:

```
<form class="example-form"   (ngSubmit)="onSubmitRegistration(user)">   

    <mat-input-container class="full-width-input">                      
        User * <input matInput name="user-userName" (ngModel)="user.userName" required>
    </mat-input-container>

    <mat-input-container class="full-width-input">            
        Password * <input matInput name="user-password" type="password" (ngModel)="user.password" required>      
    </mat-input-container>


    <mat-card-footer>
        <button mat-raised-button color="primary" type="submit">Zapisz</button>             
    </mat-card-footer>

    <br />
</form>
```

registration/registration.component.ts:

```
import {AuthService} from './../auth/auth.service';
import {Component, OnInit, Input} from '@angular/core';
import {FormGroup, FormBuilder, Validators} from '@angular/forms';
import {User} from '../auth/user';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-registration',
  templateUrl: './registration.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['../login/login.component.css']
})


export class RegistrationComponent implements OnInit {


  private formSubmitAttempt: boolean;
  errorMessage: string;

  @Input()
  user: User;

  @Input()
  createHandler: Function;

  constructor(private fb: FormBuilder, private authService: AuthService) {}

  ngOnInit() {}

  onSubmitRegistration(user: User) {
    this.authService.registration(user).then((newUser: User) => {
      this.createHandler(newUser);
      console.log('onSubmitRegistration ' + newUser);
    });
  }

}
```

Does this method  'onSubmitRegistration'  send  correctly values? The console does not display a message :

```
  console.log('onSubmitRegistration ' + newUser);
```

How to correctly add data to the database?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

solution: 
the data was badly sent to the server

registration/registration.component.ts:

```
        <form class="example-form"   [formGroup]="registrationForm"  (ngSubmit)="onSubmitRegistration()">   
               User * <input    matInput formControlName="userName"  required>
               Password * <input matInput type="password" formControlName="password" required>

                <button mat-raised-button color="primary" type="submit">Zapisz</button>             

        </form>
```

registration/registration.component.ts:

```
  registrationForm: FormGroup;
  // ... 
  onSubmitRegistration(user: User) {

      this.authService.registration(this.registrationForm.value);

 }
```

auth/auth.service.ts:

```
 registration(newUser: User): Promise<User> {  

   return this._http.post('/api/users', newUser)
    .toPromise()
    .then(response => response.json().data as User);  

 }
```